# Why can't I use string functions inside map()?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, python-3.x

The following example shows the error I am getting when trying to use a string function inside a function call to map. I need help with why this happening. Thanks.

```
>>> s=["this is a string","python python python","split split split"]
>>> map(split,s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    map(split,s)
NameError: name 'split' is not defined
```

though `split()` is an in-built function, but it still throws this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will work fine if you use `str.split()`

I.e,

```
s = ["this is a string","python python python","split split split"]
map(str.split, s)
```

gives:

```
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'string'],
 ['python', 'python', 'python'],
 ['split', 'split', 'split']]
```

The error message states: **`NameError: name 'split' is not defined`**, so the interpreter doesn't recognize `split` because `split` is not a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html). In order for this to work you have to associate `split` with the built-in `str` object.

**Update**: Wording improved based on @Ivc's *helpful* comments/suggestions.

Comment: Ah! I got it, `split()` is a method related to object type(different for `string`, `re` etc) and is not an built in function, so I need to specify the object type to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: It isn't to disambiguate, but rather because its a string method - `'blah'.split('a')` is equivalent to `str.split('blah', 'a')`, same as `instanceofmyclass.mymethod(arg)` is equivalent to `MyClass.mymethod(instanceofmyclass, arg)` - the string is the `self` argument to `str.split`.

Comment: This is kind of ugly. I'd rather call the method like a method, e.g. `map(lambda x: x.split(), s)`, or better, just go `[x.split() for x in s]`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary exactly, that's it. Since we quite frequently attach `split` to a string it's usually clear which `split` we mean.

Comment: @ivc I am not sure I follow, but I am happy to improve my wording if it is helpful. Since there are different `split` functions, how isn't this to disambiguate (or specify) exactly which of these split functions we are referring to?

Comment: @Levon because even if this particular split was the only one that existed, it would still need to be `str.split`.

Comment: @ivc your point being because it's not a built-in function, right? I already added that to my answer, I hope that's helpful.

Comment: If the downvoter will point out an error in my answer I will be happy to make a correction or improve the wording. A downvote *without* any explanation doesn't help the OP, SO or me, so is not productive.

Comment: @Levon I downvoted because of what I said in my comment above.

Comment: @isbadawi you downvoted because of aesthetics?? I didn't chose this code construct. My posting is in ***direct*** response to what the OP posted and answers exactly his concern. If you don't like his code fine, but why downvote *my* answer for explaining the problem he asked about? He didn't ask for an alternative code construct but an explanation why his code didn't work. I explained this correctly I believe. Your comment to me above really ought to be a comment to the OP at the top of the page.

Comment: @Levon If it were me, I'd explain that `split` is a method on `str` and not a builtin function. I wouldn't suggest referring to `str.split` as a function. It feels hacky and unpythonic. It's alright to point the asker in a different direction.

Comment: @isbadawi My answer already clearly states that split is not a built-in. I am not responsible for what you consider "hacky and unpythonic" .. these comments ought to be directed at OP. You also could have posted your own answer (why don't you?). I don't care about the 2 points, more the reasoning which makes no sense to me as I explained above, so there's no point in further discussion.

Comment: @isbadawi `map(str.split,...)` is definitely better than using a lambda expression. You should in general avoid that, especially in zip or map expressions (performance reasons primarily). You are right with the list comprehension, it would be the most straightforward solution. But no reason for downvote though.

Comment: @ms4py I wasn't really suggesting the `lambda`. It was just leading up to the list comprehension. :)

Comment: @Levon you're right that it isn't a built-in function, but I was addressing your "this is to disambiguate which `split` you mean" - the need to use `str.split` instead of `split` has nothing to do with `re.split` or `os.path.split` existing. It is instead related to usually spelling it as `mystring.split(sep)` rather than `split(mystring, sep)`. `str.` is needed because of how Python resolves method names, and is the same reason why the first argument to user-defined class methods is `self`. Jeff has the right of this: `split` doesn't exist, `str.split` *does*. Nothing ambiguous about it.

Comment: My +1 to Levon.  The question asks for using the `map()`.  The `class.method(instance, arguments)` is perfectly legal, and it is actually the way how classes/objects are implemented in many languages.  This is the lower-level, correct, non syntactic sugar syntax that reflects what is behind the curtain. But my +1 also to isbadawi as the list comprehension is probably *more pythonic* and more readable (unless you are a functional programming guy).

Comment: @pepr Thanks pepr I agree with you .. I myself would also have used
`list comprehension` (definitely not `lambda`) for this, but OP wasn't asking for suggestions :) but rather for *an explanation why
`map` wasn't working*. This is the first time I have received a
downvote for simply and directly answering a question correctly.

Comment: @ivc Thanks for clarifying this, I'll have to think about how I can update my answer to improve the wording and I may end up borrow your/jeff's wording, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

`split` is not a built-in function, though `str.split` is a method of a built-in object. Generally, you would call split as a method of a `str` object, so that's why it's bound directly.

Check the output from the interpreter:

```
>>> str
<type 'str'>
>>> str.split
<method 'split' of 'str' objects>
```

Comment: I don't believe that is correct (str.stplit being a built-in function). It is not listed here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html, and cleary associated with str, so a method.

Comment: @Jeff I changed it to that for you.